I need help with the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} t^a (1+t)^{1-a} e^{-b t^2} dt$
The integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} t^a (1+t)^{1-a} e^{-b t^2} dt; a,b>0$$ can be simply obtained when $a=1$ or $2$, but a general form for this integral is challenging for me.
Using Mathematica, this integral can be expressed in terms of the Gamma function and the Meijer G-function as
$$\frac{2^{a-3}}{\pi \Gamma(a-1) }  G^{3,2}_{2,3} \left(b \mid
    \begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1-a}{2},\frac{-a}{2} \\
 -1,\frac{-1}{2},0
\end{array}\right)$$
Do you have any ideas on how to derive this result?

Its asymptotic is much simpler. For example, for $b\to 0+$ the command of Mathematica 14.0 ClearAll[a, b];  AsymptoticIntegrate[   t^(a)*(1 + t)^(1 - a)*Exp[-b*t^2], {t, 0, Infinity}, {b, 0, 1},    Assumptions -> a > -1 && b > 0] // FullSimplify produces $$\frac{(a-1) a b \left(\left(-31 a^2-69 a+6 \gamma  (a+1) (a+2)-26\right) b-72 (\gamma -3)\right)+6 (a-1) a b ((a+1) (a+2) b-12) \left(2 H_a+\log (b)\right)+48 \sqrt{\pi } (a-1) \sqrt{b} (a (a+1) b-3)+144}{288 b} $$

and for $b\to\infty$ MMA 14.0 performs $$\frac{1}{48} b^{-\frac{a}{2}-2} \left(6 \sqrt{b} \left(a^3-a+4 b\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)-(a-1) a (a (a+1) (a+2)+12 b) \Gamma \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right). $$

Are you sure it's not $(1-t)$ ?

Yes, I'm sure it's (1+t).
